# I am binding dropdownlist with SQL2008 database in my WebUserControl, but my approach could use some improvement

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am doing lab. I am trying hard to bind dropdownlist with SQL2008 database in my WebUserControl. It was a piece of cake to implement when all my front and back code stood in webusercontrol, but after that I was told that this way of implementation is quite not professional. Also, I was told that I need to built a middle class with private variables and public properties:

```
public class UsersIntoDLL
{
    public UsersIntoDLL(int userID, string userName, string userFamilyName)
    {
        userID = UserID;
        userName = UserName;
        userFamilyName = UserFamilyName;
    }

    public int UserID
    { get; set; }

    public string UserName
    { get; set; }

    public string UserFamilyName
    { get; set; }
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetStudentsToDDL]
as
select UserID, UserName,UserFamilyName
from dbo.Users
```

New Method:

```
public List<UsersIntoDLL> GetStudents()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.DbConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetStudentsToDDL", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    List<UsersIntoDLL> udll = new List<UsersIntoDLL>();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {   
            //ListItem lst = new ListItem();
            //udll.Text = reader["StudentName"].ToString() + " " + reader["StudentFamilyname"].ToString();
            UsersIntoDLL students = new UsersIntoDLL((int)reader["UserID"], (string)reader["UserName"],(string)reader["UserFamilyName"]);
            udll.Add(students);
        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // here should be some reference to label located in webusercontrol. don't know
        // how to do it
        Label err = new Label();
        err.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return udll;

}
```

BadaBinding in back-code of webusercontrol:

```
CatalogAccess ca = new CatalogAccess();
    ddlStudents.DataSource = ca.GetStudents();
    ddlStudents.DataTextField = "UserName";
    ddlStudents.DataValueField = "UserID";
    ddlStudents.DataBind();
```

I am getting no errors and no binding. Students do not appear in my dropdownlist. Please help!!!

Comment: can you show us the line in the .aspx where the ddlStudents is declared?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudents" CssClass="textBox" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh you weren't setting the variables in your class properly.

Use this instead:

```
public class UsersIntoDLL {


public UsersIntoDLL(int userID, string userName, string userFamilyName) 
{ 
    UserID = userID; 
    UserName = userName; 
    UserFamilyName = userFamilyName; 
} 

public int UserID 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
} 
public string UserName 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
} 
public string UserFamilyName 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

}

Comment: My pleasure. You can thank me by pressing the up arrow next to the 0 by my answer. Also there should be a link that says "accept this answer" or something similar. It increases my rep if you do :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing immediately jumps out but have you thought about using `ObjectDataSource` [(linky)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx)

p.s. Have you checked the list isn't empty?

Comment: Damn no images no answers for new users... Looks like   ddlStudents.DataSource null object
how can it happen and what reason?

Comment: If the datasource is null then it isn't your database reading that is causing it. I'd say you aren't setting your datasource. 

The line: `ddlStudents.DataSource = ca.GetStudents(); ` 

is that inside an `if` statement? Or inside a method that isn't being called? Have you set a breakpoint on it to see if it is being hit?

Comment: Also, what did you mean by "Damn no images no answers for new users"?

Comment: I tried to upload screenshot, but system defends, saying 'You are new, and you are not allowed to upload images'

Comment: inside Page_Load method of WebUserControl

Comment: Try uploading the image to ImageShack and then posting a link to it. Did you try setting the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I tried. http://img580.imageshack.us/i/unledgw.png/ if I do understand right, it says that I am getting null datasource.

Comment: The code halts on the breakpoint before the line is executed, not after. So the datasource hasn't been set yet. Set the breakpoint on the next line and then check the datasource.

Comment: http://img864.imageshack.us/i/unledkld.png/   ddlStudents.DataTextField "" string

Comment: Is this method some good at all? Or there's some better ways to implement this simple operation without pain? But not some direct connection using datasource constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running this in Visual Studio, could you set a breakpoint on the `ddlStudents.DataSource = ca.GetStudents()` line and make sure it is not empty?

To rule other potential issues out, change that line temporarily to:

```
ddlStudents.DataSource = new { UserName = "Test", UserID = "1" };
```

and see if at least one item shows in the drop-down.

Comment: Tried to do it as you say. Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.